# can Socrata's API accept CONJUNCTIONS of WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql, socrata

i want to combine two WHERE conditions, eg using a FROM-DATE and a TO-DATE to restrict results to a data range, but don't see a way to combine these in SoQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing! You can use all the boolean operators listed within https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/where.html to combine clauses in a `$where` query.